# Link Highlighting using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I am looking for a pure Javascript/JQuery solution for Link Highlighting. It would highlight the link in such a way that if you were on the same page as the navigation link it would stand out amongst the others. The reason for the Javascript solution over css is due to an experiment on making a webpage through the use of heavy Javascript/JQuery code. I am not looking to integrate or add this to any site/code I am writing. I only want to be given proper examples to further my knowledge of Javascript/JQuery and to quench my curiosity.

Small example of a navigation bar that is on the page 'Example 3'.

http://jsfiddle.net/hPhzB/

**Html:**

```
 <nav>
    <a href="#">Example 1</a>
    <a href="#">Example 2</a>
    <a href="#">Example 3</a>
    <a href="#">Example 4</a>
    <a href="#">Example 5</a>
</nav>
```

**Short Story:**
Using javascript make a navigation system that

- Can figure out what page it is on
- Link that page to the navigation link
- Style that link so it stands out

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use CSS? Also could you provide your HTML and your attempt so far

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You could simply assign a css class to your link and use pseudo class :active in css to achieve that. Surely you could use something like jQuery(".link").attr("style", "...") to add the inline style but these guys are always to be hated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a regex in the class of the content container on a page (or the body element).

check out: http://fiddle.jshell.net/UeNdJ/

Comment: aww, other guy already got answer but mine is more complete :|

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <li id="m1">menu1</li>
  <li id="m2">menu2</li>
  <li id="m3">menu3</li>
</ul>
```

First of all, dont use js for things that you can do simply with css. css is much cheaper than  js. but if you really want to do this with js, you can set css with js.

```
$('#m2').css('background-color','blue');
```

but again, this is not the elegant way of doing this. this makes me unhappy.